# Is there a better way to record whether an app launch guide view has shown or not?

Tags: android, launch

Now I have to create a launch guide view when my app is launched at the first time. So I have to create a new flag that saved in the SharedPreferences to record whether this guide view has been shown or not. However in the future, maybe in the next severval version, I need to update the launch guide view. What I have got is to create a new flag for every new guide view? Is there any other way to do it but not create a new flag to judge my new guide view should be shown every time?

Comment: That's the simplest way. Anything more robust will require you to store information on a server on a per-user basis. I would also checkout ux.stackexchange.com - in general, stagger your guides/onboarding until the user needs to know, and always offer a "skip" button; some people just prefer trial and error.

Comment: Either introduce a new flag or make your flag an `int` and count it up for each new revision of the onboarding guide.

Comment: Thanks. At first, considering all situation, I thought that maybe I should use a boolean flag and int that compared with app version. However, I could not get out of this mess. Actually, it is okay to just an int compared with an int I set when the onboarding guide is updated to record it.